# How to pass a parameter from client side to server in python

Tags: python, flask, flask-restplus, flask-restx

I am using `flask` and `flask-restx` try to create a protocol to get a specific string from another service. I am wonder if there is a way I can pass the parameter from another function to server side.
For example, here's my server side:

```
from flask_restx import Api,fields,Resource
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

parent = api.model('Parent', {
    'name': fields.String(get_answer(a,b)),
    'class': fields.String(discriminator=True)
})
@api.route('/language')
class Language(Resource):
    # @api.marshal_with(data_stream_request)
    @api.marshal_with(parent)
    @api.response(403, "Unauthorized")
    def get(self):

        return {"happy": "good"}
```

get_answer function in a different file:

```
get_answer(a,b):
  return a + b
```

What I expect is to get the result of `get_answer` from a file, and then my API is generated so that the GET request can get it. I know that if there is a web page, we can use `render_template(` or `form` to get it. But what if I want to get the value from another function? I know we only run the server with `app.run()`, but are we able to pass any value into the server? Guessing `app.run(a,b)` should not work in this case. We definite need to pass two parameter into the server. Or we can store the answer of `get_answer(a,b)` in main with specific value of `a` and `b`, then pass the number into the server side. But it will need the parameter either way.

---

One thing I've tested is wrapping up the server into a function. But in our case, is it a good idea to wrap a class inside a function as we have `class Language(Resource):`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> get_answer function in a different file

Then import and call it

```
from other_file import get_answer

... 
def get(self):
    return {"answer": get_answer(2,2)}
```

As the other answer shows, if you want to use custom arguments, parse them from the request object

Comment: I think what i wanna to have is change the value in the model. See I got`'name': fields.String(get_answer(a,b)),` instead of in get.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the extra Flask libraries you've installed, so I don't know what `fields` object is, but at a high level, this answer is all you need to simply return results from another function